# How can I divide this shape into a single unit (eg 1x1) like gridding?

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, grid

How can I divide this shape into a single unit (eg 1x1) like gridding?

Is there a way, either opencv or algorithm or python?
I used that shape as an example, but in reality I want to split a rectangle or a square (unit cube of arbitrary size, not 1x1 in the example).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used crop method to crop certain grid.

```
cropped = img[y:y+h,x:x+h]
```

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = np.zeros((800, 800, 3), dtype="uint8")
img.fill(255)

cv.rectangle(img,(100,100), (350,600),(0,0,0),2)
cv.rectangle(img, (600,100), (350,350), (0,0,0), 2)

cropped = img[100:100+250, 350:350+250]

cv.imshow('grid',img)
cv.imshow('white',cropped)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```